# How to write a large array (1D or 2D) to hdf5 file at each time step for a simulation in Fortran

Tags: fortran, hdf5

My simulation (written in Fortran 90) produces an array (either 1D, 2D, or 3D) at each time step. I would like to output these arrays into a single HDF5 file that contains the arrays produced for all the time steps. Note that since the output array at each time step has the same rank and dimensions, it is possible to combine these arrays together by adding an extra time dimension.

For now, I just create a buffer array to combine the output array at each time step, and then write the buffer array to a dataset in a HDF5 file at the end of simulation. But if the output array at each time step gets larger, the buffer can only hold the data for a few time steps. So I need to flush the data to HDF5 every a few time steps.

I looked at many posts and documentation and found that they mentioned some techniques like chunked dataset and hyperslab selection for efficient output to HDF5. But I am still not sure how I can apply these to my case. Could someone give me an example with Fortran 90?

Comment: Welcome, please take the Welcome [tour] and use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some of the documentation on hyperslab, I got the procedure to write to hdf5 file at each time step working. The following is the demo code. Hope you find it is useful.

```
program test_hyperslab
  use HDF5
  implicit none
  integer :: error  ! error flag

  character(len=9), parameter :: filename = "subset.h5"
  character(len=8), parameter :: dsetname = "IntArray"

  integer(HID_T) :: file_id    ! file identifier
  integer(HID_T) :: dset_id    ! dataset identifier
  integer(HID_T) :: dataspace  ! dataspace identifier
  integer(HID_T) :: memspace   ! memspace identifier

  integer(HSIZE_T), dimension(2) :: dimsm = (/3, 1/)
  integer, dimension(3) :: sdata    ! subset buffer
  integer :: dim0_sub = 3
  integer :: dim1_sub = 1
  integer(HSIZE_T), dimension(2) :: count = (/3, 1/)
  integer(HSIZE_T), dimension(2) :: offset
  integer(HSIZE_T), dimension(2) :: stride = (/1, 1/)
  integer(HSIZE_T), dimension(2) :: block = (/1, 1/)

  integer(HSIZE_T), dimension(2) :: dimsf = (/3, 10/)

  integer, dimension(3, 10) :: rdata    ! data to read

  integer :: rank = 2
  integer :: dim0 = 3
  integer :: dim1 = 10

  integer :: i

  ! initialize fortran interface
  call h5open_f(error)
  ! create a new file with default properties
  call h5fcreate_f(filename, H5F_ACC_TRUNC_F, file_id, error)
  ! create the data space for the dataset
  call h5screate_simple_f(rank, dimsf, dataspace, error)
  ! create the dataset with default properties
  call h5dcreate_f(file_id, dsetname, H5T_NATIVE_INTEGER, dataspace, &
    dset_id, error)
  ! create memory dataspace
  call h5screate_simple_f(rank, dimsm, memspace, error)

  offset(1) = 0
  do i = 1, 10
    offset(2) = i - 1
    sdata = i
    ! select subset
    call h5sselect_hyperslab_f(dataspace, H5S_SELECT_SET_F, &
      offset, count, error, stride, block)
    ! write subset to dataset
    call h5dwrite_f(dset_id, H5T_NATIVE_INTEGER, sdata, dimsm, error, &
      memspace, dataspace)
  enddo

  ! read entire dataset back
  call h5dread_f(dset_id, H5T_NATIVE_INTEGER, rdata, dimsf, error)
  write(*, '(A)') "Data in file after subset written: "
  do i = 1, dim0
    write(*, '(100(1X,I0,1X))') rdata(i, 1:dim1)
  enddo

  ! close everything opened
  call h5sclose_f(dataspace, error)
  call h5sclose_f(memspace, error)
  call h5dclose_f(dset_id, error)
  call h5fclose_f(file_id, error)

  ! close fortran interface
  call h5close_f(error)
end program test_hyperslab
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need additional library for that.

Please look at the link to the Fortran library here: https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/fortran/index.html and some examples here: https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/examples/f-src.html

Comment: Hi msi_gerva, your link points to the hdf5 library, which I have already used. I just do not know how to make it work for my case, i.e., how to write a large array at each time step efficiently to a single hdf5 file.